# Public folder size is huge - digested assets - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, server, asset-pipeline

In my RoR app the production.rb has

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions = false
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  # Callback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.3'

  config.assets.prefix = "/assets-#{`git rev-parse HEAD`[0..8]}"
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
end
```

The problem is in the server, the public folder size is **15GB**. It contains a lot of folders with names like this:

```
assets-2d947fb8a
assets-64bb1c0ee
assets-6b4777157
assets-33d9c439d
assets-e6f2c6c37
assets-cb3a9bc23
assets-f1e77e02d
```

Each folder contains digested images, js, css, and more.
So, is there a way to delete/expire these assets automatically?

Comment: Why are you naming the asset folder based on the git revision? What's wrong with just using 'assets'? Rails will automatically version the individual assets when it generates them.

Comment: It looks like that is exactly the problem. It expires the old assets if they're present, but since the assets folder is different (the HEAD commit hash) for each revision, it's getting bloated. (Why? Maybe cache busting?)

Comment: @Allolex Rails assumes that `config.assets.prefix` will be the same between different versions, so it looks there to clear the old files, and to check if it needs to generate any files. Now rails looks in the directory and sees nothing there, so regenerates every singe asset every time you commit and run `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: @shelvacu. Yes, that is correct (and what I meant by "getting bloated"). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although very non-standard, I have to say, I kind of like this approach, seems cleaner to me than one huge assets dir that Rails uses now.

Anyway, if you want to keep say 10 newest assets directories and delete everything else, you can simply create a capistrano task (if you're using capistrano) and call a **shell command for the dirs expiration** from it, such as this one:

```
ls -td -- /path/to/rails/public/assets-*/ |  # list dirs, order by newest
  sed 's/.$//' |                             # remove the trailing '/'
  tail -n +10 |                              # leave out first 10 directories
  xargs rm -ri                               # delete the dirs!
```

With the `-i` option, deletion will be interactive, i.e. you will be asked to confirm every file to be deleted.  Change this to `-f` when you are sure you have the script production-ready and the dirs will be deleted silently. [SO answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136976/get-the-latest-directory-not-the-latest-file) helped me construct the `ls` part.

You can put this small "script" into a capistrano task to be called after assets precompilation during deploy.